# Keeping the data that user entered in textbox even after submit button is clicked

Tags: php, html, textbox

Basically the program is user enter number of the month for example : 12, then if you click the submit button, it will showed the name of the month, in this case December.

The problem is every time I click submit the value in textbox disappeared, I want the textbox still containing "12" even after the submit button is clicked.

Ps : Don't mind the non-English words.

```
    <form method = "post">
4. Insert month(1-12) : 
<input type="text" name="monthTxt" value=""><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>




<?php
    $monthTemp = $_POST["monthTxt"];
    $testing = $monthTemp;

    function bulan($bulan)
    {
        $months = array(1 => 'Januari', 2 => 'Februari', 3 => 'Maret', 4 => 'April', 5 => 'Mei', 6 => 'Juni', 7 => 'Juli', 8 => 'Agustus', 9 => 'September', 10 => 'Oktober', 11 => 'November', 12 => 'December');

        if($bulan < 1 || $bulan > 12)
        {
            echo "Input tidak boleh kurang dari 0, lebih dari 12, atau huruf";
        }
        else
        {
            echo $months[$bulan];
        }
    }
    bulan($monthTemp);
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without changing this all to AJAX, you need to include the `POST` variable in the form if it has been set. Change the form field's value attribute to the following:

```
<input type="text" name="monthTxt" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['monthTxt'])) { echo $_POST['monthTxt']; }  ?>">
```